# Implementing a conditional editableCellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a grid of properties. Only two columns, `name` and `value`. I want to edit the `value` column using a select input when the `name` of the property equals certain value. How can achieve this?

I did this, but the editor keeps on edit mode and doesn't return to it's default state.

```
editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm">'
                  + '<select ng-if="row.entity.name == \'someValue\'" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"></select>'
                  + '<input ng-if="row.entity.name != \'someValue\'" type="INPUT_TYPE" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" />'
                  + '</form></div>'
```

Comment: Can I ask first, why you have your template in a single quoted variable ? It makes your code a little illigible :/

Comment: Kinda irrelevant to the issue...anyway, if I use double quotes I would have to escape the double quotes on the HTML...

Comment: My mistake, I thought you were talking about Angular2+, the tag for AngularJS is `angularjs`